# int to bitstring function to handle negative numbers

Tags: c, binary

How would I change this function to handle negative numbers?  It correctly outputs everything but it does not make the leading bit 1 when negative.   I can't do a negative check then simply force the first bit to be 1 because the amount of 0s between the leading bit and rest of the numbers will be off.

```
char* fromInt(int bin){
  static char str[33];
  str[1] = '\0';
  int n;
  for (n = 128; n > 0; n >>= 1){
      if( (bin & n) == n){
          strcat(str, "1");
      }else{
          strcat(str, "0");
      }
  }
  return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is:

```
char* fromInt(int bin)
{
    static char str[33];

    str[0] = '0' + ((bin & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000);
    str[1] = '\0';
    for (int n = 0x40000000; n > 0; n >>= 1) {
        if ((bin & n) == n)
            strcat(str, "1");
        else
            strcat(str, "0");
    }
    return str;
}
```

The function has two steps. First is to determine the setting of sign bit (assuming that `int` object has 32 bits and it uses two's complement arithmetic):

```
(bin & 0x80000000) == 0x80000000
```

yields either `1` or `0`. Because it's about the sign, It might have been written simply as:

```
'0' + (bin < 0)
```

The second step is to loop over remaining bits from position 30 to 0, like in the original code.

Here is an example program:

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", fromInt(0));
    printf("%s\n", fromInt(1536));
    printf("%s\n", fromInt(-1));
    return 0;
}
```

This will output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011000000000
11111111111111111111111111111111
```